# Why can't I get the 100 point reputation boost for my home improvement and productivity accounts?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts, association-bonus

https://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/660/inquilinekea?tab=accounts is where all my accounts are. And I did try to clear account associations. But to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the reputation bonus, **you have to associate your accounts from the site where you have 200+ rep**. Initiating the association from a child site like Productivity will not work.

So in [your case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165137/inquilinekea?tab=accounts), you'll probably want to initiate the account association from either Astronomy or Meta, where you have over 200 points.

Comment: Yes, exactly. [This is covered by the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#login).

Comment: I just tried it. And I'm still not getting the 100 point rep bonus. =/

Comment: See http://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/660/inquilinekea?tab=accounts

Comment: I'm almost certain that the site association bonus has changed to be bidirectional since the launch of the SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: By bidirectional, do you mean that I should expect such a bonus?

Comment: Isn't the association automatically done, when the same OpenID account is used for all the accounts?

Comment: I really don't know if this has changed. The only bit of documentation I can find confirms my answer. I haven't associated any accounts from anywhere other than Stack Overflow, though, so I can't confirm anecdotally either. We'll need someone else to provide the official word.